# Extract variable from text file during Docker build

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'm creating a Dockerfile and part of the process is to `ADD` the latest version of a package, which can be downloaded as a text file.

### Getting the latest-version.txt file

```
ADD http://example.com/latest-version.txt
```

### Contents of the latest-version.txt file

```
package1 = AB1.0.0
package2 = 32.4132
package3 = 123.456
```

### The goal

Search for the string `package1`, set the variable `packageVersion` to `AB1.0.0` and `ADD` the file.

```
ADD http://example.com/package1.${packageVersion}.tar.gz
```

Can I achieve this in the Dockerfile or will I need some help from a Bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible Answer

I don't think the `Dockerfile` syntax will support what you want out of the box currently. I would suggest you create a simple `bash` script to do the downloading/renaming for you and then just `ADD` the static file pointers to your `Dockerfile`.

## Example

- Pull your version file eg. `ADD http://example.com/latest-version.txt`
- Add/run some simple bash script/oneliner to process your version file (see below a suggestion to get started)
- This script reads the `latest-version.txt` file and downloads the relevant files, eg.

  - `wget http://example.com/package1.${packageVersion1}.tar.gz -O /tmp/package1.tar.gz`
  - `wget http://example.com/package2.${packageVersion2}.tar.gz -O /tmp/package2.tar.gz`
  - etc
- Since all relevant packages have been saved to static file names you can hardcode it in your Dockerfile as eg.

  - `ADD /tmp/package1.tar.gz`
  - `ADD /tmp/package2.tar.gz`
  - etc

## Closing thoughts

I would suggest you employ some kind of [Configuration Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management#Operating_System_configuration_management) (CM) to make your life easier as this method of solving issues can get messy quickly. CM has the upside of providing not only more structure to solve problems like this, but also two other important attributes namely `idempotence` and `convergence` when building an artifact.

## Appendix

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  NAME=`echo $line | cut -d '=' -f1`; VERSION=`echo $line | cut -d '=' -f2`; echo $NAME; echo $VERSION;
done < latest-version.txt
```

Comment: @Bjoem Thanks for the answer.  Using a bash script is what I thought that I'd need to do.  I may still need some help to create this.  I'm guessing that I should use something like SUBSTRING.  The version control txt file and packages are from a 3rd party, so I can't change how this is done.

Comment: @JasonBerryman added a trivial oneliner to the answer to get your bash script started. Good luck!

Comment: @Bjoem Thanks for the great answer.  That's really helped.  Although progress has stopped due to another issue (unable to install httpd with centos:latest).  Things are never straightforward :) Hopefully, your efforts won't go to waste.